# Does deleting a row in a database makes that database  free up space?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Inserting a row in a database adds up data to it. Does deleting a row free up space in that database? Or will the row just be deleted without changing the amount of used space?

Comment: Is this about mysql or (microsoft) sql server? You tagged both!

Comment: Why have you tagged both `MySQL` and `SQL-Server`? The specifics will be different for both and so this is two different questions.

Comment: @MartinSmith This could be a nice question just on how different DB systems deal with the space from removed rows.

Comment: @TheNail - But on the other hand a comprehensive answer just for SQL Server could easily be very lengthy. And how will the OP pick a correct answer if all of them are correct but about different RDBMSs?

Comment: Someone who needs the points can answer: "It depends" :-) But I see your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL, it depends on from whose standpoint. For example, if you can insert a million rows before running out of disk space, if you delete half of them, then you have space to insert a half million more again. (Ignoring transaction logging-- just imagine that the logging is done elsewhere)

The data file, after it has grown, will not shrink. So the drive space used by the data file isn't available to the OS or any other application.  Until, a database shrink operation is done. That re-arranges the data inside the file to free up space on the drive for the OS or other application to use.

Comment: if I am understanding your answer, the database would reuse the space, but if it was 10GB before the deletion, it would remain 10GB, even though it was half a million rows smaller.  Is that correct?

Comment: @DataGirl Yep, that's what happens. The DBA would have to run maintenance on the mdf file to shrink it, if the actual physical disk space needed to be reclaimed.

Answer (score 3):

When you use Oracle, space from removed rows can be reclaimed immediately using [specific commands](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_alter_table_shrink_space_command.htm). Otherwise it will stay reserved for new rows, as @oymustang86 mentions.

Answer (score 2):

[Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1336002638218) says for Oracle :

> When you delete the data from the table -- the blocks will go onto the
>   freelist for that  table (assuming the amount of space on a block that
>   was freed fell below the pctused).   These blocks will be used for
>   subsequent inserts and updates into this table.
>
> When you delete data from the index -- if the block the index entry
>   was on is now "empty" 
>   -- that block will go back onto the freelist to be used anywhere in the index struct.   Else that block stays where it is and data that
>   would naturally go onto that block  (because of where it is in the
>   b*tree) will go there.
>
> Space is effectively reused when you delete.  Your database will not
>   show any new free  space in dba_free_space -- it will have more blocks
>   on freelists and more empty holes in  index structures.

Comment: Just for clarity: this applies to Oracle databases.